# download and save zip file to iphone

Tags: iphone, download, zip

i want to download the zip file from web but unable to figure out that how it is possible

i can download image /text/xml file but unable to download a zip file

Can someone guide me how to download zip files from web?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [`NSURLConnection`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html), it works exactly the same way no matter which type the file has.

---

**Example:** (typed off of my head, no guarantee that it works this way and you should obviously implement error checking)

```
- (void) download
{
    self.loadedData = [NSMutableData data];         // make 'loadedData' a property of the class

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://..."];
    NSMutableURLRequest  *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                               cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                                           timeoutInterval:20.0];
    [urlRequest setValue:@"Optional User Agent" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];

    // shoot it off
    NSURLConnection *mainConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
    if (nil == mainConnection) {
        NSLog(@"Could not create the NSURLConnection object");
    }
}
```

Then you must handle the incoming data in the delegate methods, e.g. to just save your data:

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [loadedData appendData:data];
}
```

Take a look at the **other delegate methods** and implement them, you should deal with authentification challenges and fail responses. You can also for example set:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
```

in `connection:didReceiveResponse:` and set it to `NO` again in `connectionDidFinishLoading:`.

Comment: Hi Pascal,Thanks for this code. its works for me. and i simply save the nsdata in file as i save other files(png,txt, xml).

Comment: @rupesh can you share your code, as i am also looking for simple example