# download .zip or .doc file on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, download

i want to download .zip or .pdf or .doc file on iphone from server via webservice request
and webservice is deploy on IIS.

i dont know anything about it

Comment: possible duplicate of [download and save zip file to iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407313/download-and-save-zip-file-to-iphone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This piece code downloads a pdf and saves it to a temporary location

```
NSData *pdfData = [NSData  dataWithContentsOfURL:pdfURL];
NSString *fileName = [[pdfURL path] lastPathComponent];
NSString *filePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSError *writeError = nil;
[pdfData writeToURL: fileURL options:0 error:&writeError];
if( writeError) {
   NSLog(@" Error in writing file %@' : \n %@ ", filePath , writeError );
                                            return;
}
NSLog(@"%@",fileURL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use NSURLConnection or better yet ASIHTTPRequest to download the file as NSData which you write to a file.